Делать с ними что хочет - запятая
Нужна ли запятая в выражении "а потом делать с ними что хочет"?
Делай что хочешь - не нужна, но здесь оно разделяется вставкой "с ними"...

Правильно:
...а потом делать с ними что хочет.
Пояснение
Оборот с подчинительным союзом что хочет является устойчивым сочетанием, употребленным в значении одного члена предложения, поэтому запятой нет.
Вставка с ними не мешает такому пониманию. Сравнить: а потом поступать с ними по-всякому, любым образом.
